# How to retrieve parent object by filtering out from the child object in java stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Person is my root POJA and I have list of phone number of as my child object.

```
String firstName;

String lastName;

Long id;

List<String> phoneNumber = new ArrayList<>();

int age;


public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age, Long id, List<String> phone) {
    super();
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
    this.id = id;
    this.phoneNumber = phone;
}

List<Person> personList = Arrays.asList(
    new Person("Abdul", "Razak", 27, 50L, Arrays.asList("100", "101", "102")),
    new Person("Udemy", "tut", 56, 60L, Arrays.asList("200", "201", "202")),
    new Person("Coursera", "tut", 78, 20L, Arrays.asList("300", "301", "302")),
    new Person("linked", "tut", 14, 10L, Arrays.asList("400", "401", "402")),
    new Person("facebook", "tut", 24, 5L, Arrays.asList("500", "501", "502")),
    new Person("covila", "tut", 34, 22L, Arrays.asList("600", "602", "604")),
    new Person("twitter", "tut", 64, 32L, Arrays.asList("700", "702", "704"))
);

List<String> list = personList.stream()
    .map(p -> p.getPhoneNumber().stream())
    .flatMap(inputStream -> inputStream)
    .filter(p -> p.contains("502"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I would like to retrieve person whose numbers equals to specific string. Is it possible to achieve this by using stream ?.

```
List<String> list = personList.stream()
    .map(p -> p.getPhoneNumber().stream())
    .flatMap(inputStream -> inputStream)
    .filter(p -> p.contains("502"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In simple, How to retrieve parent object by filtering child object ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
personList.stream().filter((person)->person.getContacts().contains("100"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Will give you the matched `Person`.

Comment: Thank you. Assessed too highly by using flatmap to get child object

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to retrieve person whose numbers equals to specific
>   string

```
List<Person> list = personList.stream().filter(p -> p.getPhoneNumber().contains("502"))
                     .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

This shall get you the list of `Person` whose list of `phoneNumber`s consists of "502" as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `List<Person> collect = personList.stream().filter(person -> person.phoneNumber.contains("502")).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: to get person phonenumber list... you can also get it by getter method or by calling . operator. Have you tried this code ? It is working fine.. please check before commenting